# Trying to mysqli_query to INSERT INTO my database. Not receiving errors

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm trying to make a very basic form that inserts into my database. I've worked through countless hours working on this. I feel I understand each line of code. I can't imagine what the problem is. I'm not receiving any errors, although I haven't set up error checks in my code yet. Hopefully my problem is simple and obvious.

Here is my connect.php file. $con is my connection to a new mysqli. talk is my database.

```
<?php
$con= new mysqli("localhost","root","","talk");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Here is the relevant form part of my html. title and content and the two pieces of information I'm trying to insert into my database. I include the connect.php. The textarea should be linked to the form through the form="talkform". This form uses action="process.php", which I'll cover next.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
?>

<center>
<h1>/talk/</h1>

<form method="post" action="process.php" id="talkform">
    <input type="text" name="title"/><br><br>
    <textarea form="talkform" rows="10" cols="80" name="content"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="talk" />
 </form>
```

And here is my process.php. I included connect.php in this file as well. Not sure if that's redundant and causing problems, but I don't think so. I also used this $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] bit you see, which I picked up from a tutorial. Not sure if there's a better way of accomplishing that. I put everything into variables. When I was working through errors, it was all on the mysqli_query line. I have the strongest suspicion that's the culprit.

```
 <?php

include 'connect.php';

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST')
{

$title = $_POST['title'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$operation = "INSERT INTO
                main(title, content)
            VALUES($title, $content);";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $operation);     
}
    ?>
```

I hope that I didn't leave anything out. I've been struggling with getting a database working for over a week. It's been a painful process, and although I'm learning a lot, I'm not getting anything to work. Please help, and thank you.

Comment: Change your query to `"INSERT INTO main (title, content) VALUES('". $title ."', '". $content . "');"`

Comment: `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST')` assigns "POST" to the variable, change it to use the comparison `==`

Comment: Think Different got it perfectly right. God I am filled with joy. I did spend a lot of time fiddling with those quotation marks and periods, but couldn't get it right. Could someone explain how those work and how to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `==` operator to compare

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

and quote your query variable

```
$operation = "INSERT INTO main(title, content) VALUES('$title', '$content');";
```

so code looks like with escape string

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
   $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
   $operation = "INSERT INTO main(title, content) VALUES('$title', '$content');";
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $operation);     
 }
```

Also better to use check for post values exist or not with `empty()` or `isset()`

Answer (score 0):

Line 4: `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`

Better is check out directly if form was sent using `if (isset($_POST['title']))`.

When you call `mysqli_error()` you´ll find our you try to insert strings without quotes (and you don´t escape inputs - look for SQl injection).

```
$operation = "INSERT INTO main(title, content) VALUES('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $title) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $content) . "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not checking for errors after your `mysqli_query` call, of course you won't see any.
2. You're vulnerable to SQL injection. Use mysqli's prepared query syntax to avoid that. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
3. Your immediate problem is that your query reads `... VALUES(foobar, baz)`, which is invalid. You're missing quotes around the values. However, if you properly use prepared statements, that will become a non-issue, so ignore that.